# can table_calendar return the visible days?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the latest version available (3.0.9) of [table_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) which, according to its [changelog 1.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar/changelog#110), allows to get the first and last day showed on screen:

> Removed onFormatChanged callback - it is now integrated into onVisibleDaysChanged callback

unfortunately, I'm not finding `onVisibleDaysChanged` anywhere. It's like the library is out of sync with the documentation? I'm wondering how I can get the upper and lower bound of my calendar, without any further calculation.